# Is there a way to share a Swift state between separate files?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Is there a way to share a Swift state between separate files? I've tried:

```swift
public struct VideoPlayerControlsView : View {
    @State public var playerPaused : Bool = true
    // More Code Here
}
```

And would like to reference this in another file (where the two are linked, so I can change one and the other would reflect this change), I think that it would be achieved by a Binding:

```swift
struct VideoView: View {
    @Binding var videoPos : Double
    
    //more code here
}
```

But then I'm told: `'init(videoPos)' declared here'` alongside that I should change:
`PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(VideoView())` to `PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(VideoView(videoPos: <#Binding<Double>#>))` but not sure what to set the place holder value to, I also don't think this is the right way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

How can I do this?

NOTE:
I'm using Swift Playgrounds on Mac

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to share state between different files in a Swift Playground?

Comment: @jnpdx yes, this is correct, I'll update it in the question

Comment: IIRC Swift playgrounds would require you to add a `public init` in each view.

Comment: For the placeholder, just use a constant value: `.constant(0.5)`

Comment: Hi @aheze I don't understand what you mean, please could you expand? Cheers,

Comment: You might want to look at https://support.apple.com/guide/playgrounds/work-with-shared-files-itcdd72f72c4/mac  In general, you're fighting an uphill battle trying to do this in a Playground rather than just a normal iOS or macOS project.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind is that state (and especially `@State`) should *always* be private, you generally never have a `public` state. It is for the internal use of the view only, such as animation or other view-related stuff.

To solve your problem, however, are two sophisticated ways of doing what you are trying to do:

1. Create a Model

   The model should be the only source of truth. For your video player, you might consider adding a model that represents just that: A video player. Now the example above is not really a model (but the ViewModel in the MVVM paradigm) but it serves as a good example:

   ```swift
   class VideoPlayer: ObservableObject {
       @Published var isCurrentlyPlaying = false
   }
   ```

   You wire this up to your struct via either a `@ObservedObject` or a `@StateObject` (preferred) outlet to your view. You can pass it down the view hierarchy using the `EnvironmentObject` methodology. Now all of this is pretty complicated stuff if you have never heard of this, so maybe [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-observedobject-to-manage-state-from-external-objects) might help you.

   2. Pass state via binding

   I will start with the example:

   ```swift
   public struct VideoPlayerControlsView : View {
       @Binding public var playerPaused : Bool
       // More Code Here
   }
   ```

   ```swift
   struct VideoView: View {
       @State private var playerPaused: Bool
       var body: some View {
           // some more code
           VideoPlayerControlsView(playerPaused: $playerPaused)
       }
   }
   ```

   There are several (more or less) subtle differences:

   Note that the 'state' in the controls view is actually the binding. Also note that you don't initialize the binding. A `@Binding` represents a way to 'read and write' from the source of truth. And there should (again) only be one source of truth. This source of truth comes from the VideoView.

   Also note that you 'pass' the state somehow to the controls view, not the other way around. But be careful here since you don't actually pass the *State* but rather a 'way of reading and writing' from and to the state

Hope this clears things up a bit!

Comment: Hi, I have been trying at this for the last hour, I've tried again with your suggestion but cannot get it to work. If you catch a moment, I would really appreciate for you to look at the playground here (for Mac) : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a7a90b77d2ee665c92fabd00a779b89020210625205256/373906 (weTransfer). The main content is in Main, and the rest is in VideoPlayer.swift. My main objective is to get the videoPos and playerPaused states/variables in the Main file where I can easily access them. It would be really, really appreciated! Cheers,

Comment: So you want to have them in the file `Main`? Then declare them there :P
You'd then pass them *down* with bindings